# Conditional formatting AND OR

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to conditionally format a cell to indicate if that cell = Y and an adjacent cell = EMAIL or TEXT, highlight the original cell. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My example starts in cell A1. Using formula

```
=AND($A1="Y",OR($B1="Email",$B1="Text"))
```

I've then applied this to range `=$A$1:$B$4` which with a Red fill gives me:

[image]